# AWS Using modified storage volume

Tags: amazon-web-services

I modified my aws instance from 30GiB to 450GiB but it doesn't seem to get updated:

```
$ df

Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              499572        0    499572   0% /dev
tmpfs             101444     3152     98292   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      30428648 29815896    596368  99% /
tmpfs             507220        4    507216   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             507220        0    507220   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             101444        0    101444   0% /run/user/1001
```

`$ df -i` looks fine

Any idea how to "adapt" the volume/storage of the instance?

Answer (score 0):

If your filesystem is ext2, ext3 or 4 try resize2fs /dev/xvda1
You might need to mount the volume on another instance first (stop your current instance, detach volume, attach to another instance, mount it, and run resize2fs on the volume), stop instance, detach volume and reattach it to your desired instance.